# What is the area that 1 litre of gasoline would spread above the sea?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I am studying for a general chemistry test with Atkins and Jones "Principles of Chemistry" 5th edition.

In the **Chapter 18**, **page 743**, **section 18.3**, there is this *funny* question:

> How would you estimate the area that 1 litre of gasoline would spread
>   above the water surface?

**Observation:** I translated it from the Brazilian Portuguese edition. The English version may have different units, but the idea should be the same.

Let's say that the water body is the sea. But it could be a big lagoon, too. It doesn't really matter.

It got me thinking and now I'm stuck. How can we do that?

Comment: Estimate the thickness of the layer, take 1 litre and divide by the thickness.. otherwise you probably need more data

Comment: If we had more data, what is the best way to do this? I thought about using surface tension properties and equations, but I am not sure if it is the easiest way...

Comment: You can calculate the surface area per molecule, using surface tension measurements

Comment: For an _estimation_ I might start with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_spill#Estimating_the_volume_of_a_spill) table regarding the dispersal of oil spills on water. I would assume that gasoline would spread at the very thin end of that table, and guess something on the order of 50 nm thickness and say that's the amount you can see or some such thing. There is no reason it couldn't spread much thinner, too thin to see even.

Comment: This site offers a hand rail: http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.08/h/phillip4.html  Be careful, as it mixes SI and non-SI units; but the principle is legible.

Comment: These articles were helpful! I think I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: One simple way is to estimate the molecular size and assume the layer is one molecule thick. A check on the thickness estimate is the interference patterns on the surface which mens the layer must be of the same order as the wavelength of visible light. Either way, you will get a crude but useful estimate.

Comment: Benjamin Franklin tried this experiment on the pond in Clapham Common in London  in the 1770's.  There is an account in the link below which also contains his own account.  http://www.rsc.org/learn-chemistry/content/filerepository/CMP/00/000/687/isms-9.pdf?v=1399160447243  or search for Franklin Oil Drop Experiment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint [here](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.08/h/phillip4.html) assumes a layer thickness of (crude) oil of about 1 mm. If I remember the pictures in the News around Deepwater Horizon correctly, and compare what I saw with own eyes at the local petrol station, petrol has a lower viscosity; likely spreads out wider than crude oil.

From [here](http://www.physics.utah.edu/~woolf/2020_Jui/apr22.pdf) we learn the layer thickness is *much* lesser than 1 mm (millimetre), namely 168 nm (nanometre); hence all these colourful interference patterns in visible light.

$$ 1 \text{ L} = 1 \text{ dm}^3 =  10^{24} \text{ nm}^3$$

Deviding by 168 nm provides with googles built-in calculator an area of about $$5.95 \times 10^{21} \text{ nm}^2 = 5952 \text{ m}^2$$

To set this into a context, UEFA and FIFA agreed on the size of European Football / Association (soccer) field ($ 105 \times 68 \text{ m}$) which equals $7140 \text{ m}^2$.

Addendum:  According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_field), an American Football field measures "$120.0 \text{ yd } (109.73 \text{ m}) \times 53.3 \text{ yd } (48.74 \text{ m})$ or $6400 \text{ yd}^2 (5351.2 \text{ m}^2$)".